# Putting an image in a table using FLWOR

Tags: html, xml, xquery, flwor

```
<pizzeria>
   <logo>logo.jpg</logo>
   <pizzas>
       <pizza id="p001">
           <nombre>Carbonara</nombre>
           <imagen>carbonara.jpg</imagen>
       </pizza>
       <pizza id="p002">
           <nombre>Barbacoa</nombre>
           <imagen>barbacoa.jpg</imagen>
       </pizza>
       <pizza id="p003">
           <nombre>Gourmet</nombre>
           <imagen>gourmet.jpg</imagen>
       </pizza>
       <pizza id="p004">
           <nombre>Boloñesa</nombre>
           <imagen>bolonesa.jpg</imagen>
       </pizza>
   </pizzas>
</pizzeria>
```

They ask me to put the logo image and the other images (the other images in a table) in exist db using FLWOR. The images are stored in a folder called "images". If you need any more info, please, tell me.

I tried this:

```
{
  for $h in doc("/db/exercise/pizzeria.xml")//pizza
  return
    <tr>
      <td>{$h/imagen}</td>
    </tr>
}
```

But it obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating HTML, then you want an [`img` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) with the `@src` attribute pointing to that image file:

```
{
for $h in doc("/db/exercise/pizzeria.xml")//pizza
return
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/{$h/imagen/text()}" alt="{$/nombre/text()}"/></td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: You forgot the images. But thanks! ```<td><img src="images/{$h/imagen/text()}" alt="{$h/nombre/text()}"/></td>```